# How to select all parents of a child from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

My table is called Employees.

It looks like this:

```
EmpID   ManagerID   EmpName
-----   ---------   -------
1       NULL        Ali
2       1           Mike
3       1           Tom
4       2           Kim
5       2           Rob
6       3           Lay
7       5           Paul
8       7           Sam
9       6           Bin
```

I am trying to build a query that returns all parents of the children

So the query would return the parents of Bin and Sam are

```
Bin, Lay, Tom, Ali
Sam, Paul, Rob, Mike, Ali
```

I tried this but wasn't successful

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees B ON A.ParentID  = B.EmpID 
WHERE A.EmpID IN (8,9)
```

but this can only work for 1 parent

How can I get the whole list of parents (managers)?

Comment: Google "recursive cte sqlserver"

Comment: You want to have as many columns as there are managers?
The worst case here is that you n-1 managers (n being the number of employees)

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want have variable column quantity? It is not usual way to use sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `recursive cte`

```
WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT *
        FROM Employees WHERE EmpID IN (8,9)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT emp.*
        FROM Employees emp JOIN Parent ON emp.EmpID = Parent.ManagerID
)
SELECT distinct * FROM Parent
```

Answer (score 2):

Using recursive cte.
The solution would be finding the top hierarchy of each employee and grouping by them using string aggregate we can get all the employee names under each top manager in the order of thier level in hierarchy.

```
WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT *,empid as top_hierarchy,0 as level
        FROM Employees  WHERE EmpID IN (8,9)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT emp.*, parent.top_hierarchy, level+1
        FROM Employees emp JOIN Parent ON emp.EmpID = Parent.ManagerID
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(EmpName,', ') within group(order by level) 
FROM Parent group by top_hierarchy;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e17b2/1/0